# Why does this Ant error not prevent the whole system(Java Pet Store) from running?

Tags: java, ant, glassfish, build-error

I'm studying the Java Pet Store project(a little dated) . When running the setup, I have to run `ant` I get this error:

```
C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\apps\petstore>ant
Buildfile: C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\apps\petstore\build.xml

default-ear:

-pre-compile:

bpp-actual-compilation:
     [echo] Compiling petstore
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\apps\petstore\build\web\WEB-INF\cl
asses
    [javac] Compiling 40 source files to C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\apps\petstore\buil
d\web\WEB-INF\classes
    [javac] C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\apps\petstore\src\java\com\sun\javaee\blueprint
s\petstore\model\CatalogFacade.java:39: package javax.servlet.annotation does no
t exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\apps\petstore\src\java\com\sun\javaee\blueprint
s\petstore\model\CatalogFacade.java:41: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class WebListener
    [javac] @WebListener()
    [javac]  ^
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\bp-project\command-line-ant-tasks.xml:78: Compile failed; s
ee the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds

C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\apps\petstore>
```

After that I do other setup things (asadmin start-database, then 
But afterwards when asadmin start-domain domain1 , then ant deploy ).

But finally I go to the final web-page destination ( `http://localhost:8080/petstore/faces/index.jsp` ) , and it works(picture)!

[image]

And here is the build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Copyright 2006 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.  You may not modify, use, reproduce, or distribute this software except in compliance with the terms of the License at: 
 http://developer.sun.com/berkeley_license.html
 $Id: build.xml,v 1.56 2007-03-16 15:29:15 basler Exp $ -->

<project name="petstore" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project petstore.</description>

    <property name="is.war.module" value="true"/>
    <property name="default.javac.target" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="default.javac.source" value="1.5"/>
    <import file="bp-project.xml" />

    <available property="bp-ui-5-jar.exists" file="lib/bp-ui-5.jar"/>    
    <target name="create-bp-ui-5-jar" depends="init" unless="bp-ui-5-jar.exists">
        <ant dir="${bp-ui-5.home}" inheritAll="false" inheritRefs="false"/>
        <!-- copy appropriate jars that are needed in petstore -->
        <copy todir="lib/">
            <fileset dir="${bp-ui-5.home}/dist"/> 
        </copy>
    </target>    

    <target name="-post-compile" depends="init">
        <!-- copy property files into build directory -->
        <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir="src/java">
                <include name="**/*.properties"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <mkdir dir="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        <copy todir="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
            <fileset file="./build/catalog-persistence.jar"/>
            <fileset file="${file.reference.lucene-core-2.0.0.jar}"/>
            <fileset file="${file.reference.bp-ui-5.jar}"/>
            <fileset file="${file.reference.shale-remoting.jar}"/>
            <fileset file="${file.reference.commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar}"/>
            <fileset file="${file.reference.commons-io-1.2.jar}"/>
            <fileset file="${file.reference.commons-logging-1.1.jar}"/>
            <fileset file="${file.reference.jdom.jar}"/>
            <fileset file="${file.reference.rome-0.8.jar}"/>
            <fileset file="${file.reference.rome-fetcher-0.7.jar}"/>
        </copy>        

        <copy file="src/conf/persistence.xml" todir="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF"/>

        <antcall target="insert-proxy-settings"/>
    </target>

    <target name="insert-proxy-settings">
        <copy todir="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/" file="web/WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
        <concat destfile="${build.dir}/proxy.properties">proxy.host=${proxy.host}
            proxy.port=${proxy.port}
            <filterchain>
                <expandproperties/>
            </filterchain>
        </concat>
        <!-- Replace value of the proxy settings in web.xml for Google maps -->
        <replace file="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml" propertyFile="${build.dir}/proxy.properties">          
            <replacefilter token="@@proxy.host@@" property="proxy.host"/>
            <replacefilter token="@@proxy.port@@" property="proxy.port"/>
        </replace>        
    </target>

    <target name="unzipIndexes">
        <unzip src="lib/petstoreIndexes.zip" dest="${javaee.domaindir}/lib/petstore" overwrite="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="setup" depends="init, create-bp-ui-5-jar">
        <mkdir dir="${javaee.domaindir}/lib/petstore/images"/>
        <ant dir="." antfile="setup/setup.xml" target="setup" inheritAll="false" inheritRefs="false"/>
        <antcall target="unzipIndexes"/>
    </target>

    <target name="unsetup">
        <ant dir="." antfile="setup/setup.xml" target="unsetup" inheritAll="false" inheritRefs="false"/>
    </target>

    <target name="checkLines">
        <fixcrlf srcdir="./src" tab="remove" tablength="4" eol="unix" includes="**/*.properties,**/*.jsp,**/*.html,**/*.sh,**/*.java,**/*.xml" excludes="**/ja/**" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Why did it let it run, but before it said there's a failure ? How do I fix that error message(or do I even need to?) ?

Comment: Probably the library jar missing where that `javax.servlet.annotation` package lies while build time, but supplied by the server while runtime. `C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\apps\petstore\build.xml` how does that look like?

Comment: @BheshGurung - Sure, I'll add that here too (build.xml)

Comment: There's no `deploy` task. Are you sure you're deploying what you think you are, and not just an old version?

Comment: @DaveNewton - Hmm, yeah I think you're right. Let me look into this. So  how old of a version may be lingering around?

Comment: No clue. Are you sure you posted the correct ant file? I don't see a `bpp-actual-compile` task, either.

Comment: maybe the missing targets are inherited from the <import file="bp-project.xml" /> ? As already mentioned the compilation problem is most likely caused by the missing library. the javax.servlet packages are part of the Servlet API (servlet.jar from j2ee) and are not included in java se. But every servlet container (e.g. tomcat) has to provide an implementation as shared .jar. Add servlet.jar to the classpath for the compilation and it should work. But take care to not include it into the webapp (in WEB-INF/lib), as it must be provided by the servlet container!

Comment: @DaveNewton - I'm fairly certain, because it's in the dir. `C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\apps\petstore`

Comment: @Pyranja -  I'll need to spend time to understand what you mean here, Thank You Very Much!

Comment: @Adel It's not, because the targets in question do not exist in it. It includes another file; the targets must exist in there, or elsewhere. This might be a good time to learn about `grep`. Somewhere in the compilation task it will refer to a classpath. That classpath is incomplete.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Got it! I'll learn about 'grep' then and figure this out, Thank You Very Much!

Comment: To ensure that you are actually deploying the petstore app that you are building, modify the petstore/faces/index.jsp page in a way that will make it easy for you to see your change, and then re-run the build and deploy it.

Comment: @bakoyaro- Thank You , I will do so.